# How do I increase the text size in an app on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, fonts, text

I had to re-download the Brackets text editor amongst a few other apps but when I open it up the text in the menu, buttons in the app text in the app itself are really small, I think there's a command line way of doing it.

Here is a screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 4):

In `Brackets` use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> to increase text size and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> to decrease it.

The current font size will be stored in `Preferences` and will persist between launches of the program.

The same will apply to apps such `Firefox`.

[Additional reference](https://trello.com/c/fJGmZlJx/462-2-increase-decrease-code-font-size)

Comment: I did that already it increases the font size but the buttons on the side panels remain miniscule.

Answer (score 1):

On my end I use 200% in the Display preferences (see screenshot below). That way everything is bigger.

The other day, though, it stopped working for Qt applications... until I rebooted. Whenever the OpenGL drivers of NVidia get updated, the currently installed version is locked in place and new windows can't get a valid surface. After rebooting, everything worked like a charm again.

[image]